# Read email outlook via Java EE on localhost

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, outlook, imap, jakarta-mail

I created an application with 3 virtual machines and I supervise all these machines with Nagios.

I use nagios to send me email to my Outlook on localhost with postfix and I went to got all mail with a Java EE application and put them in my database.

How can I extract all my email from MS outlook with Java EE and put them in my database?

I use IMAP in postfix to send email to Outlook on my localhost

I have Outlook version 2007 and Windows 7

Cordialement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780870/ideas-about-linux-based-solutions-for-parsing-email-storage-files-of-ms-outlook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [there is nothing named "JEE"](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE).  The correct name is "Java EE".

Second, Outlook is an email client.  Exchange is the email server.  If the messages are on the Exchange server, and the Exchange server is configured to allow IMAP access, you can use JavaMail to read all the messages on the server.  Start with the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

If the messages are really on your desktop/laptop machine, stored in the Outlook client, e.g., because you've configured Outlook to download all the messages, store them locally, and remove them from the server, then you have a much harder problem.  Outlook stores the messages locally in a Microsoft proprietary format that JavaMail doesn't directly support.  There are some [third party tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) to help read such messages.