# Spring MVC - HTML or Redirect

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm converting Java EE code to Spring MVC.

Original application has some code, which may return redirect HTTP code or regular response.

```
 if (doRedirect)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).cookie(cookie).location(new URI(authUrl)).entity("Redirecting...").build();
    else
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(authUrl).cookie(cookie).build();
```

How do I express the same logic using Spring MVC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what framework you are using, never seen code like

```
Response.status(Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).cookie(cookie).location(new URI(authUrl)).entity("Redirecting...").build();
```

So I'm going to assume that this from some custom / proprietary framework your project uses.

UPDATE: From the comment I understand this is Jersey code. Thanks. Definitely something I'm going to look into! :)

Nevertheless, a Spring MVC app is still a Java EE app. If your controller method logic dictates that the response will either be a client side redirect, or a an html, you can do the following.

1. Have your controller method `ModelAndView` object.
2. Based on your logic, if you decide that the method should issue a redirect, create an instance of `RedirectView`, passing the uri to which the redirect should happen.
3. Set the `RedirectView` instance into an instance of `ModelAndView` and return it from the method. This will cause a redirect on the client's browser.
4. If your logic dictates that an HTML response should be served, pass the path to your jsp to the `ModelAndView` instance and return it.

Hope its clearer now.

Basically, Spring MVC allows controllers to accept and return different types of objects, so pick the signature that works best for you. Whatever you do, using Container specific API and creating raw response (HTML) in the controller method is not encouraged, because it blurs the separation of concerns between the view and the controller in MVC.

UPDATE 2:
1. You can very well use an external (absolute) url with `RedirectView`.
2. The `RedirectView` takes care of setting the response status and the `Location` header.
3. If you want to set a cookie in the response, use the standard Java EE API - `HttpServletResponse` as an argument to the controller method, and whatever cookies you want to add, directly to it.

Comment: Should I make my Controller method void and just manipulate response?

Comment: Im going to update my response, with something more concrete.. and a simpler solution.

Comment: We redirect to external site, not sure that RedirectView helps in this situation.

Comment: Thank you. 
1) As you see in the example code, the returning HTML is just URL. It seems to be too complex create a jsp view for returning just one String. Can I return come content in ModelAndView w/o creating a jsp? Currently we do not have any View and ViewResolver as most of the application is REST with JSON responses
2) Will it work - both return ModelAndView and manipulate HttpServletResponse in the same Controller method?

Comment: If you want to stay away from views and view resolvers, then return void, and manipulate the response object as you please. Just as a side note, I use views, even with my REST application, to abstract away view specific things like cookies, headers, jsonp handling etc away from all controller methods and into one shared "JsonView" instance.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide some example code of using such shared JsonView?

Comment: forgot to mention, yes you can manipulate the response, and have a view return type, Spring ensures that if you opened an output stream to the response in your controller, the returned model and view or view is completely ignored.

Comment: I can provide a sample, but I think it would be better if that is posted as a separate question. Just list down the type of things you want to do with all responses, and you might get more answers from other users. In the meantime, if you think this question is answered sufficiently please consider accepting an answer

Comment: @ArjanTijms - I see you've edited JEE to Java EE. May I know why? JEE is a standard abbreviation. Within the context of this question there cannot be any ambiguity about its meaning. I don't mind the language of the answer being corrected for better understanding, but editing JEE to Java EE doesn't seem constructive at all to me.

Comment: @AkshaySinghal JEE is not the official term and also not a standard abbreviation, that would be just "EE". See https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE Note that SO itself also automatically renames JEE to Java EE (see stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms, filter on JEE). See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762084/read-email-outlook-via-java-ee-on-localhost/17765090#17765090 Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the return type of your controller is `ModelAndView`, wrap a `RedirectView` to make a redirection.

```
 if (doRedirect)
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(authUrl));
 else
    return new ModelAndView(url);
```

If the return type of your controller is `String`, append `"redirect:"` to the url where you want to redirect.

```
 if (doRedirect)
    return "redirect:" + authUrl;
 else
    return url;
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I set cookies and headers with this approach?